# IOS: Switching text fields using segmented control

Tags: ios5, xcode4

I'm currently developing a Body Mass Index calculator for the iPhone using segmented control to switch between the various weight and height units, at the moment I have a text field in which the user inputs the values.

My question is this; is there a way to change the text field to two separate text fields?

For example if the user selects "stone & lbs" from the segmented control the single text field will be replaced by two text fields for input in stones and lbs.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have a view Controller. The job of that controller is to control views.

So, as an indicator, Have your view controller create and display one text field when for a unit selection that takes one value, and that creates, and displays two text fields when using something that needs two text fields.

The controller can also take care of hiding the fields that aren't being used, and you can even use UIView animation to attractively animate the changes from single to double text views.